# Substitution in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

I have been trying to understand this solution and I can not wrap my head around the fact that $a_{11}$ = $a_{22}$ = 0. What is this conclusion based on? Is it due to the fact that they are related by A and its transpose $A^T$?

Can not imbed the picture due to this being my first post:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr6G7.jpg

Comment: Links or images with mathematical expressions can be typed. Please try to type the context of your link.

Answer (score 1):

It is because $a=-a \iff a=0$.

Comment: I think that I understand now. The second and third step is not included. Thanks.
$$
a_{11} = -a_{11}
$$

$$
2a_{11} = 0
$$

$$
a_{11} = 0
$$

$$
a_{11} = -a_{11} = 0
$$